# [GraphQL error]: Message: insert or update on table "XXX" violates foreign key constraint "XXX", Location: [object Object], Path: XXX

Tags: postgresql, graphql

I thought and clearly do not, understood FK's. To explain/justify the reasoning behind my table structure.

- We have multiple artists
- Each artist can have multiple awards
- Each award can have multiple award information

Why can I not have the fk `awards_artists_artist_id_fk` on award when each award needs a unique artist for each award?

### Error

```
[GraphQL error]: Message: insert or update on table "awards" violates foreign key constraint "awards_artists_artist_id_fk", Location: [object Object], Path: createAward
```

### Mutation

```
gql`
  mutation (
    $awardName: String!
    $artistId: Int!
  ) {
    createAward(
      input: {
        clientMutationId: "createAward"
        award: {
          awardName: $awardName
        }
      }
    ) {
      award {
        artistId
        awardName
      }
      clientMutationId
    }
  }
`
```

### Tables

```
Artists
   artist_id
Awards
   award_id
   artist_id
Awards_Info
   awards_info_id
   award_id
   artist_id
```

### FK

```
awards
    awards_artists_artist_id_fk = artist_id > artist_id
awards_info
    award_info_artists_artist_id_fk = artist_id > artist_id
```

Answer (score 0):

So in the end I was missing a record in the DB that my code was asking for...

`artistId: artistDetails.length ? artistDetails[0].artistId : 0`

There was not artist with an ID of `0`